# How to find out the table involved in deadlock?

Tags: sql-server, spring, hibernate

I am running a website based on Spring, JPA/Hibernate, Tomcat, and MS SQL Server. When reviewing the system logs, I noticed a few lines like the following:

```
SqlExceptionHelper:146 - Transaction (Process ID 61) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

I know what deadlock is, but I hope to know which table was involved in the deadlock. How can I get this information?

Please note that I am not able to see this error in the development environment. I am not able to find this information in MS SQL server either.

Comment: Since you can not see the error from SQL Server, and you see the log after it really happened, I think you maybe add the query logs when get this exception, it will more helpful to trace error.

Comment: Troubleshooting deadlocks can be a little complex. I would suggest capturing more information using extended events. You can find more information on how to set it up in these articles. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31280.finding-and-extracting-deadlock-information-using-extended-events.aspx OR https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/03/extended-events-doesnt-hard/

Comment: Su and FFSQLGuy, thanks so much for your input!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SQL server profiler to trace the "Locks / Deadlock graph" events.
Hopefully you'll get everything involved: Objects and queries.

Comment: Edgard, am I right that once a trace is started, it always runs and the events related to deadlock and table names will be recorded in server logs?

Comment: It will only be recorded in "SQL Server Profiler" himself (Or in the trace file, if you ask the profiler to record the trace in a file). SQL Server Profiler is a totally independent tool ; He only record events for himself. You can either let it running, or record everything in a separate ".trc" file.

Comment: I tried the profiler tool. Though I only selected "Lock / Deadlock graph" and save the traces in a file. It seems that the profiler records everything, instead of waiting to catch deadlock events, and the .trc file grows quickly. How can I make it only record deadlock events?

Comment: You'll have to check the "Let the server handle the data" checkbox (Just below the filename) and save the trace in a shared directory. The trace should not grow very large.

Comment: Thanks so much for your follow up!